# pure virtual destructors in c++ Clion and VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clion, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

I'm trying do declare pure virtual destructor,
in VS2019 I'm writing like that:

```
    virtual ~A() = 0 {};
```

and it's fine, but in Clion don't accept that
I'm getting the following message:

> pure-specifier on function-definition virtual ~A() = 0{ };

and it forces me to write a different implementation for the function (not that it to much trouble but id like to know why is that)

Comment: I just was about to edit :D

Comment: Pure specifier and definition at the same time is not valid indeed. It would probably be a good idea to fill a bug report.

Comment: _in VS2019 I'm writing like that: `virtual ~A() = 0 {};` and it's fine_ That might be a native extension of MS (and not the first one I recognized).

Comment: In the declaration, `virtual ~A() = 0;` and provide an implementation after the declaration `inline A::~A() = default;` (because it is a destructor, it still needs to be provided).  If the implementation is in the .cpp file, omit the `inline`.  If the destructor needs to do something other than `default` provide the destructor behavior as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the C++ 20 (11.6.3 Abstract classes)

> 2. ...[Note: A function declaration cannot provide both a pure-specifier and
>      a definition — end note] [Example:

```
struct C {
  virtual void f() = 0 { }; // ill-formed
};
```

> — end example]